# RMI exception: java.lang.InvalidClassException InvalidClassException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a abstract serialize class in two jar files:

Jar 1:

```
public abstract class TestDTO implement Serializable{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -8068828541601342858L;
}
```

Jar 2:

```
public abstract class TestDTO implement Serializable{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -8068828541601342858L;
}
```

I have same serialVersionUID  on both of the jars but it still gives this exception:

java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:
java.io.InvalidClassException: com.test.TestDTO; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 7584986215301760999, local class serialVersionUID = -8068828541601342858

Anyone know why this is happening and what is the solution for this problem?

Comment: The problem seems to be that you are deserializing a `TestDTO` that was **created** using a version of the class that is different to what is in both JAR 1 and JAR 2.  And the fact that the both JAR 1 and JAR 2 declare the class abstract is really fishy.  You can't have an instance of an `abstract` class ...

Comment: we are not creating an instance of that class, one jar is a base jar and the other is its child as we say

Comment: is that issue with rmi registry?

Comment: 1)  If you are not creating instances of `TestDTO` somewhere, where did the serialized objects come from?  2) Potentially, yes.  You haven't said anything about where these serialized objects are coming from.

Comment: Hi Stephen, maybe an extended class we are creating somewhere in the project. but we have checked the serialUID number which is the same in both the jar but still getting this issue do you have any idea how to debug or tackle this issue

Comment: The value `7584986215301760999` is coming from somewhere.  Find out where.  My bet is that it is a serialized object.  Figure out where that serialized object comes from.